# how t restore a hdfs deleted file

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I was asked with below question .

Interviewer: how to recover a deleted file in hdfs.
Me: from trash directory we can copy/move back to original directory.
Interviewer: Is there any other way except from trash recovery.
Me: I said No.

So my question is , whether there is really any way to recover deleted files  or interviewer just asked me to test my confidence.

I have found below way to recover which is different from hdfs -cp/mv but it is also getting file from trash .

hadoop distcp -D ipc.client.fallback-to-simple-auth-allowed=true -D dfs.checksum.tpe=CRC32C -m 10 -pb -update /users/vijay/.Trash/ /application/data/vijay;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hadoop has provided HDFS snapshot (SnapShot) function since version 2.1.0
You can try to use it

First，Create SnapShot

```
hdfs dfsadmin -allowSnapshot /user/hdfs/important
hdfs dfs -createSnapshot /user/hdfs/important important-snapshot
```

Next,try to delete one file

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r /user/hdfs/important/important-file.txt
```

Final,restore it

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/hdfs/important/.snapshot/
hdfs dfs -cp /user/hdfs/important/.snapshot/important-snapshot/important-file.txt /user/hdfs/important/
hdfs dfs -cat /user/hdfs/important/important-file.txt
```

P.S:You have to use CP Command （not MV Command） to recover deleted file in this way Because the deleted file in snapshot is only-read file

Wish my answer can help you

Answer (score 0):

During the interview, you were asked about recovering deleted files in HDFS. Your answer about retrieving data from the trash directory was correct.
However, it's important to note that there are other methods to recover files in HDFS, such as:

- using snapshots (if enabled)
- replication factor
- professional data recovery software

Your discovery of a command that retrieves files from the trash shows a useful technique that's frequently used in HDFS systems.
Although your response was accurate, showing flexibility and problem-solving abilities by being open to considering different options and sharing your ideas throughout the interview would have been a plus.